# how to fix this reflection code in java?

Tags: reflection

i am trying to make a test runner first class is test runner and second one is class that testet and last one is my main page.. i want to reach the tester method with method invoke but this is not working.

```
    public class tester {

        public tester()
        {

        }

        @Test
        public void testTopla(){
            int sayi1 = 10;
            int sayi2 = 20;
            int gercekSonuc = 30;
            //
            islem isl = new islem(sayi1, sayi2);
            int sonuc = isl.topla();
            Assert.assertTrue("Sonucta Hata Var", sonuc == gercekSonuc);
        }

    and this is what i am testing
    public class islem {
        private int sayi1;
        private int sayi2;

        public islem(){

        }
        public islem(int sayi1, int sayi2){
            this.sayi1 = sayi1;
            this.sayi2 = sayi2;
        }

        public int getSayi1() {
            return sayi1;
        }

        public void setSayi1(int sayi1) {
            this.sayi1 = sayi1;
        }

        public int getSayi2() {
            return sayi2;
        }

        public void setSayi2(int sayi2) {
            this.sayi2 = sayi2;
        }
        public int topla(){
            return this.sayi1 + this.sayi2;
        }


    and this
public class Deneme1UI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = Deneme1UI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

     Class hilmi = tester.class;

       tester obj = new tester();


        for(Method method : hilmi.getDeclaredMethods())
        {   
            method.invoke(obj);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29

the first parameter of the invoke() function needs to be an instance of the reflected class
in your case an instance of the class `tester`

you will have to create an instance of the `tester` class before you can invoke its methods

Comment: thanks, i tried this Object obj = hilmi.newInstance(); method.invoke(obj); but doesnt work

Comment: what exception do you get? because it should work. unless it has no constructor without arguments

Comment: unhandled exception type illegalaccessexception

Comment: i guess `tester obj = new tester();` fails too? is your constructor private? can you show the definition of the constructors of the class tester?

Comment: tester obj = new tester(); works but method.invoke(obj) doesnt work

Comment: now i have this exception method.invoke(obj) _invocationtargetexception

Comment: since you are unwilling to share the part of the code that isnt working, i cant help you, give a fully compilable example that gives you the error and i can help you

Comment: testerpublic class tester {

 public tester()
 {
 
 }
 
 @Test
 public void testTopla(){
     int sayi1 = 10;
     int sayi2 = 20;
     int gercekSonuc = 30;
     //
     islem isl = new islem(sayi1, sayi2);
     int sonuc = isl.topla();
     Assert.assertTrue("Sonucta Hata Var", sonuc == gercekSonuc);
 }

Comment: works for me, both `tester obj = new tester();` and `Object obj = hilmi.newInstance();` work without problem when using `method.invoke(obj);`

Comment: i edited the question that including my codes could you please look at